# how to have a Link from main query to sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I am inserting two values from one table to another table. One of the inserted values comes from concatenating three column values.
I am using the below query, but the error says "subquery has more than one value."
We can't include "top 1" into sub query which gives same value to all.

```
insert into dbo.tblCrucibleLdgDtls (R2IGTNo,TotalMtrlWgt) 
Select  R2IGTNo,
   (select RTRIM(LTRIM(( CONCAT(ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt,ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt,ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt)))) as TotalMtrlWgt 
    from dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails 
    where ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt is not null or ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt is not null or ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt is not null 
   ) 
from dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails 
where  R2IGTNo like '%C%'
```

From Table

[image]

Solution may be simple. I am not a expert.There is no duplicates and (ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt,ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt,ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt) has unique relation with R2IGTNo. Like  if R2IGTNo has b1 then ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt has value,  if R2IGTNo has b2 then ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt has value, if R2IGTNo has b3 then ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt has value. with that condition query can be altered.
pls suggest.

Comment: Suggestion: enable line number in SSMS, indent your code and read at what line number you have the `subquery has more than one value`: there is where your error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by using cte, suggestion got in MS forum

```
insert into dbo.tblCrucibleLdgDtls (R2IGTNo,TotalMtrlWgt) 
    Select  R2IGTNo, coalesce(ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt,ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt,ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt) as TotalMtrlWgt     from dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails     where  R2IGTNo like '%C%'
```

or

```
    with cte1 as(
select R2IGTNo,RTRIM(LTRIM(( CONCAT(ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt,ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt,ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt)))) as TotalMtrlWgt 
        from dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails 
        where R2IGTNo like '%C%'
        and (ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt is not null 
        or ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt is not null 
        or ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt is not null))
insert into dbo.tblCrucibleLdgDtls (R2IGTNo,TotalMtrlWgt) 
select * from cte1
```

Anyway Thank you all. -shankar

Answer (score 0):

Give alias names to the tables:

```
SELECT ..., (SELECT ... FROM  dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails wdA)
FROM  dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails wdB
...
```

Now the inner/nested sub query can reference `wdB`, and it will mean the outer instance of the table.

But also, this has the look of something that would be better done with a JOIN, APPLY, or windowing function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what type of rows you are getting from the inner query. If your inner query returns multiple duplicate rows then the solution is simpler, just use a distinct -

```
insert into dbo.tblCrucibleLdgDtls (R2IGTNo,TotalMtrlWgt) 
Select  R2IGTNo,
           (select distinct RTRIM(LTRIM((CONCAT(ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt,ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt,ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt)))) as TotalMtrlWgt 
            from dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails 
            where ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt is not null or ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt is not null or ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt is not null 
           ) 
from dbo.tbl1RMWeighingDetails 
where  R2IGTNo like '%C%'
```

But if your inner query returns multiple rows which are different from one another then you have to revisit your requirement.

Comment: There is no duplicate rows.  in these three (ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt,ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt,ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt)  column one only will have value others will be null. and it has unique link with R2IGTNo. in that way also query can be written. but i don't know how to write.

Comment: I think i might know the problem! Can you try replacing the OR with AND.

Comment: actually i feel we have to use alias name as said by Joel Coehoorn. or we need alter query instead of using concatenation. because if R2IGTNo has b1 then ULTotalS1S2MtrlWgt has value,  if R2IGTNo has b2 then ULTotalS3S4MtrlWgt has value, if R2IGTNo has b3 then ULTotalS5S6MtrlWgt has value.